# Regex pattern matching doesn't work specifc string in java

Tags: java, regex, encoding, rxtx

I was using a REGEX pattern in java (given below):
[image: Working Pattern]

for the string: 
[image: working string]
It works fine. But when I tried using the below pattern:
[image: non working pattern]

for the string:str =

[image: nonworking string]
Sorry about the image upload. Looks like the character '[]' in a00[] is encoded differently on the browser. Any ways to read that character in a different manner? The same character has a different representation in notepad++. I'm using RXTX and inputStream.read(readBuffer) to read the data. Is there any way I can update my encoding methods in java to overcome this?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FydBg.jpg
i.imgur.com

P.S: Sorry about the image description - if it type it out i cant represent that character.
      when i copy paste that character, it becomes an empty space.

Comment: Did you take that shot with your phone or something? You couldn't just use unicode (eg `"blah\u0123blah"`) and paste in the code?

Comment: +1 for the "screenshots". ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strange symbol (└) looks like how ASCII 3 is represented in some fonts.

In Regex, `\b` matches a word boundary. That is, between an alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric character. It works in the first case because there is a digit ("9") before the matched substring, and an exclamation mark ("!") right after it (which is a non-alphanumeric character).

In the second case you changed the exclamation mark to a letter, so there is no longer a transition from alphanumeric to non-alphanumeric.

The solution is to extend the Regex so it also matches the symbol and digit:

```
Pattern.compile("(\\x03\\d)(a)\\w*(?=\\x03\\d)");
```

I used `\\x03\\d` to match the codes. The last part `(?= )` is a look-ahead. It checks if it matches, but does not consume it. This is so, so you do multiple matches in a row.

---

A simpler alternative, would be to just split the string on "└", and examine the pieces.

```
s.split("\u0003")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help MizardX. I'm still confused with the part (\\x03\\d). What does this regex mean? is there any sample input and output data? Is the unicode for └ = \u003? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters

Comment: "└" is just how the character looks in some fonts. `\u0003` is how you write ASCII character 3 in java, or `\x03` in Regex. `\x03\d` matches ASCII character 3 followed by a digit (`0`…`9`).

Comment: Thanks again for the timely help MizardX. One last question : Pattern.compile("(\\x03\\d)(a)\\w*(?=\\x03\\d)");  In this (a) refers to the alphabet 'a' that its starts with?

Comment: `( )` is a capture group. `a` matches the literal string "a". I based the pattern on your original pattern. See [regular-expressions.info/brackets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)